# Replace string with JSX element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I want to format a date time like this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
```

if I return a string is like this:

```
2016-07-02 20:14:12
```

some code is like this(all code is [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-dateformat/blob/master/lib/dateformat.js#L98)):

```
let token = /d{1,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|[LloSZWN]|'[^']*'|'[^']*'/g;
mask.replace(token, (match) => {
      if (match in flags) {
        return flags[match];
      }
      return match.slice(1, match.length - 1);
    });
```

The problem is now I want the number is wrapped by `React.Component`, such as:

```
<span>2016</span>-<span>07</span>-<span>02</span> <span>20</span>:<span>14</span>:<span>12</span>
```

I want to point out that the wrapped element is not always `span`, maybe a component defined by myself, such as `MyComponent`

Comment: How is `mask` defined?

Comment: @TimoSta https://github.com/felixge/node-dateformat/blob/master/lib/dateformat.js#L98

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Note: this is plain string computation. You can check the logic and update for JSX.

```js
var str = "2016-07-02 20:14:12";
var result = str.split(" ").map(function(a){
  var delimeter = a.match(/[^0-9]/)[0];
  return a.split(delimeter).map(function(item){
    return "<span>" + item + "<span>";
  }).join(delimeter);
}).join(" ");

document.getElementById("result").innerText = result;
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

For JSX I guess you can try something like this:

```js
var str = "2016-07-02 20:14:12";
var result = str.split(" ").map(function(a){
  var delimeter = a.match(/[^0-9]/)[0];
  return a.split(delimeter).map(function(item){
    return <span>{item}<span>;
  }).join(delimeter);
}).join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that existing libraries doesn't fit my requirements. So, of course, I have written my own:

https://github.com/EfogDev/react-process-string

It is very easy to use. Your case example:

```
let result = processString({
    regex: /[0-9+]/gim,
    fn: (key, match) => <span key={key}>{match[1]}</span>
})(mask);
```